# ¡como puedo agregar un id consecutivo a cada boton?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat= "row in data | filter:getFilter">

    <td>{{row.folio}}/td>

    <td>{{row.fecha}}/td>

    <td>{{row.nombre}}/td>

    <td>{{row.usuario}}/td>

    <td>{{row.departamento}}/td>

    <td>{{row.descripccion}}/td>

    <td>{{row.correo}}/td>

    <td> button href="" id="" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-aprobacion" ng-click="aprobar();">Aprobar /button>

    </td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría mediante {{$index}} que si lo utilizamos dentro de un ng-repeat cada vez que se llame nos devuelve la iteración actual (0,1,2,....), y si lo concatenamos con un string inventado por nosotros obtenemos un id único. Lo ves mas claro en tu propio código:

```
<tr ng-repeat= "row in data | filter:getFilter">

    <td>{{row.folio}}/td>

    <td>{{row.fecha}}/td>

    <td>{{row.nombre}}/td>

     <td>{{row.usuario}}/td>

    <td>{{row.departamento}}/td>

    <td>{{row.descripccion}}/td>

    <td>{{row.correo}}/td>

    <td> button href="" id="MiIndiceInventado{{$index}} class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-aprobacion" ng-click="aprobar();">Aprobar /button>

    </td>

</tr>
```

Los "id" obtenidos serian:

MiIndiceInventado0
MiIndiceInventado1
MiIndiceInventado2

y así sucesivamente.